# STM32L412 PWM doesn't run

Tags: embedded, stm32

I moved from an STM32F031K6 to an STM32L412 for more speed. I found that the PWM no longer works in my code, but im unsure why. I am using cubeIDE and have the relevant outputs selected as PWM outputs. The setup preamble from the cubeIDE is as follows -

```
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{


TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};
TIM_BreakDeadTimeConfigTypeDef sBreakDeadTimeConfig = {0};

htim1.Instance = TIM1;
htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
htim1.Init.Period = 0;
htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
{
Error_Handler();
}
sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}
sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
sConfigOC.OCNPolarity = TIM_OCNPOLARITY_HIGH;
sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
sConfigOC.OCIdleState = TIM_OCIDLESTATE_RESET;
sConfigOC.OCNIdleState = TIM_OCNIDLESTATE_RESET;
if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}
if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}
if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim1, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateRunMode = TIM_OSSR_DISABLE;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.OffStateIDLEMode = TIM_OSSI_DISABLE;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.LockLevel = TIM_LOCKLEVEL_OFF;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.DeadTime = 0;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakState = TIM_BREAK_DISABLE;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakPolarity = TIM_BREAKPOLARITY_HIGH;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.BreakFilter = 0;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2State = TIM_BREAK2_DISABLE;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Polarity = TIM_BREAK2POLARITY_HIGH;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.Break2Filter = 0;
sBreakDeadTimeConfig.AutomaticOutput = TIM_AUTOMATICOUTPUT_DISABLE;
if (HAL_TIMEx_ConfigBreakDeadTime(&htim1, &sBreakDeadTimeConfig) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}

HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim1);

}
```

Before I just set up the timers with the inbuilt cube software - all i needed to do was put a number in the output compare register. Now it doesn't work, I don't know what I'm missing - I noticed that the timers aren't enabled by the HAL setup but when I enable them in TIM1_CR1 it still doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

A Timer that counts from 0 to 0 doesn't count much.
Maybe you should change the upper counter limit:

`sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;`

Comment: sConfigOC.Pulse = 0; 

seems to control the value in CCMR1, do you mean the htim1.Init.Period = 0; ?

I tried to change them both (and one at a time) to 65535 but it makes no difference